# Alert sounds on iMac

Tags: high-sierra

Just got a new iMac and it is making an alert type beep every 30 secs. I have tried turning everything off in notifications but this isn't stopping it. The only thing that helps is turning the volume off completely which I don't want to have to do. Can anyone help please?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! :) Could you please [edit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/322659/edit) your question to provide more info. For example, does this happen every time you log in? Does it happen when you have nothing else running (e.g. no Mail open, no browser open, etc)? Have you got any external hardware connected to your iMac?

Answer (score 2):

To start with I would boot into Safe Mode as a troubleshooting step to see if that makes any difference.

**Boot into Safe Mode**

Follow these steps to boot your Mac into Safe Mode:

1. Fully shut down your iMac
2. Restart your iMac
3. Immediately press the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key and **keep it down**
4. Let go of the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key when you see the login window (NOTE: If you have FileVault enabled you may need to log in twice).
5. Take a note of what happens (i.e. does it still beep every 30s in Safe Mode)
6. Exit Safe Mode by restarting your iMac as normal
7. Test again to see if the beeps continue

Let me know how it went and we'll go from there.